# Mocking static function member

Tags: c++, unit-testing, googletest, googlemock

I'm trying to mock a **static function member** with gmock. I found a section on the [gMock Cookbook](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/master/googlemock/docs/cook_book.md) that talks about Mocking Free Functions. However it is not clear to me..

For instance, I have a static function called **isActiveMode** that I want to mock. Instead of calling **isActiveMode** directly, I have to introduce an interface for it and have a concrete subclass that calls the static function:

```
class MyClassInterface { 

public:
...
virtual bool isActive() = 0;

};

class MyClass: public MyClassInterface { 

public:
...
virtual bool isActive() 
{ 
    return isActiveMode();
} 

};
```

Then I define the mock class:

```
class MyMock {

public:
MOCK_METHOD(bool, isActive, (), (override));

};
```

But this does not seem to work.. 
Does somebody have a clue on how to make this work?

Answer (score 2):

Your mock class should be derived from the interface class.

```
class MyMock : public MyClassInterface {

public:
MOCK_METHOD(bool, isActive, (), (override));

};
```

If that doesn't help, please provide a [minimum reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) showing how you are using the mock.